# What is the baseline font height of FontAwesome font?

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I created a font icons set with FontAwesome icons and free icomoon icons set with [Icomoon app](https://icomoon.io/app) . The default baseline in the app is 6.25%  .

When I compare default FontAwesome icons and FontAwesome icons from icomoon app they are off by few px. In the image below , the button on the **left** is using default FontAwesome font , the button on the **right** is using same font icon created with icomoon app.

[image]

You can see that the icon in the button on the right is up by 2px or so.

Their CSS is almost same and using FontAwesome CSS does not change the fact that baseline is off and  **I don't want to adjust this via CSS**

icomoon

```
font-family: 'Myicons';
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
```

FontAwesome

```
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
font-size: inherit;
text-rendering: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing:
```

Do you know what baseline is FontAwesome using ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

FontAwesome uses a baseline height of about 14% (of the em height). You can find that out for yourself by looking at the code of the SVG font provided by FontAwesome.

Comment: naild it mr icomoon. thnx. Do you think I would have issues with  14%  and other icon fonts or they will all fall on same baseline as FA ?

Comment: thnx about svg info  but can you be precise where to look ? 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
I never bothered before so it would be great to find that out for the future.

Comment: A font can only have one baseline. So yes, they will all have the same baseline. When you change the baseline in the IcoMoon app, the live font preview (in the font tab) gets updated so that you can see how they align next to some text with the same font-size.

Comment: In the SVG font, look for "descent" and divide it by "units-per-em". Multiply by 100 to get the percentage.

Comment: THANKS! this is what to configure in ICOMOON preferences to work with both: font-awesome and icomoon. 
Now my icomoon icons align the same as all other bootstrap texts and font awesome icons (Y)

Comment: The precise value is `14.28571428571429%` (100% * 256 / 1792). Also, Font Awesome's 4 font has been moved to here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/fa-4/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg

Comment: For the other two values, if you use Em Square Height (power of 2): 1024, and Whitespace Width (% Em): 25 , it is almost exact compared to native FontAwesome 4.7.